# Spring Integration - Router, task-executor and smart LB

Tags: spring-integration

I have a queue channel and a chain with poller and task-executor "listening" on that channel, doing some processing in parallel. What I would like to do is to configure it in such a way that I could route particular messages based on some logic/property to make sure that particular message 'type' is always being process by particular thread from the task-executor.

Example: messages where: `PAYLOAD_PROPERTY & 1 == 0` go always to thread 1, `PAYLOAD_PROPERTY & 1 == 1` to thread 2 (please notice that this is just an example for 2 threads - I could easily use router here but I can imagine there is logic - like modulo operation - for 10 threads as well) - another words: thread 1 and thread 2 cannot process concurrently same 'type' of message. So the purpose is not just to load balance it - it is to stick with the same thread based on some logic.

My initial thought was to somehow use channel dispatcher (it can have `load-balancer-ref` and `task-executor`) but not sure if this would work as I have a chain with poller which do the processing I need further.

Can you advice what is the best component(s) setup to have workflow like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing like that in a "standard" task executor.

It's probably easier to remove the queue channel have a router (subscribed to a direct channel) route to 10 separate executor channels, each configured with a single-thread executor.

Comment: Yes, `recipient-list-router` is what I could use but having that with 10 `recipient` tags looks... I thought that there might be something smarter.  So, you recommend router here?

Comment: It's either that or you would need to somehow create a custom task executor.

Comment: Fair enough - thanks for your suggestion. BTW: I have noticed some strange behavior - I have defined name for the threads I configured with task-executor for a poller but I can see `task-scheduler-X` names in console log - do you know where these come from and why? Is the code being executed within different thread than the one from poller/task-executor?

Comment: Spring Integration [defines a `TaskScheduler` bean\(http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-taskscheduler) used for polling (and other scheduled tasks). If the poller has a `taskExecutor`, the scheduler hands the task over to it.

Comment: I have still some doubts - I have `<int:chain...><int:poller fixed-rate="100" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" max-messages-per-poll="10" receive-timeout="150" task-executor="exec"/>... </chain>` and `<bean id="exec" class="...ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="threadFactory" ref="exec-factory"/>
... </bean>` and of course exec-factory with thread name defined but still I can see some of the jobs are being executed by `task-scheduler-X`, some of them are being handed over but some not. Is it related with number of available threads in executor - not enough or it is something different?

Comment: It is in poller having its own executor and each of the thread in this executor is then, based on the router logic being send to queue channel with second poller with executor (one thread each) and I have an issue with the second poller. Hm.

Comment: Don't put XML in comments; it's unreadable - edit your question instead. It depends on configuration of the TE and the `RejectedExecutionHandler` in the TE, the default is the `AbortPolicy` but you can configure a `CallerRunsPolicy` in which case, if the TE has a bounded queue, the task will run on the calling thread (in this case the executor). If you still can't figure it out, edit your question with a snippet of the log you are concerned about and show the complete configuration of the poller/TE.

Comment: Sorry for the XML - I thought it will be faster. Anyway I have `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy` set as `rejectedExecutionHandler`... - ok I will try to figure it out, if not I will edit the question. Thanks!

Comment: In my previous comment, `s/(in this case the executor)/(in this case the scheduler)/` CallerRuns with the bounded queue means if the queue is full, the task will run on the scheduler thread. Spring Integration provides a `CallerBlocksPolicy`.

Comment: `CallerBlocksPolicy` does the magic - this is what I needed here. Beautiful -
 thanks again!